# Cannot load PHP on Windows nanoserver IIS PHP dockerfile

Tags: php, windows, iis, dockerfile, nano-server

I have the following working with microsoft/iis, but I would like to get it working with the smaller nanoserver. When I replace microsoft/iis with nanoserver/iis this line fails. Is it because exe files cannot run in nanoserver?

```
C:\vc_redist-x64.exe /quiet /install
```

```
FROM nanoserver/iis
```

This works:

```
FROM microsoft/iis 

ADD PHP_7.3.26-NTS.zip C:\\php.zip
#unzip
RUN powershell -Command "expand-archive -Path 'c:\php.zip' -DestinationPath 'c:\test'"
#check path for source file php folder name if it changes!
RUN powershell -Command "Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose 'c:\test\PHP_7.3.26-NTS' -Destination 'c:\php'"

ADD vc_redist-x64.exe C:\\vc_redist-x64.exe
ADD php_wincache.dll c:\\PHP\\ext\\php_wincache.dll
ADD php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll c:\\PHP\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll
ADD php_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll c:\\PHP\\ext\\php_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll
ADD php.ini C:\\php\\php.ini

# Enable required IIS Features
# Install VC Redist 14
# Configure IIS
# Configure system PATH
RUN dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /All && \
 C:\vc_redist-x64.exe /quiet /install && \
 del C:\vc_redist-x64.exe && \
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='c:\php\php-cgi.exe'] && \
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='c:\php\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Unspecified'] && \
[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC',value='C:\PHP'] && \
 setx PATH /M %PATH%;C:\PHP && \
 setx PHP /M "C:\PHP"

# Optional: Add a starter page
RUN powershell.exe -Command "'<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | Out-File C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php" -Encoding UTF8

# ADD any application content and perform any configuration below
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

ADD web.config C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\web.config
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40131 You'd better use Server Core, or use the workaround mentioned in the thread.

Comment: You also can use a PowerShell script to copy the binaries.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e502f85a-dec0-4b0d-81f4-e0daf6dd2b5f/how-do-i-install-a-required-visual-c-redistributable-on-nano-server?forum=NanoServer

Comment: I would like to use nanoserver because of the small size. I tried copying VCRUNTIME140.dll directly to nanoserver. When I run php on the command line it exits with no error.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with Nano Server in Docker, on a Windows Server 2019 implementation under VMWare Workstation 16.

At first, none of my Visual Studio 64-bit applications (console-mode variants of my WIN-PROLOG compiler) would run in Nanoserver - but then I found the solution. I simply manually copied the latest 64/64 version of vcruntime140.dll into the same folder as my application, and bingo - everything worked perfectly.